# removing fields from manager

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde, fieldmanager

I have a parent screen for my application in which there are 4 custom managers,custommanagers1, custommanagers2, custommanagers3, custommanagers4 for all the screens of my application it is enough if I manage to change the custommanager2(removing fields and adding fields).

Any sort of help is welcomed

A Y

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
myManager.replace(oldField, newField)
```

If not, I'm not getting the question.